# @babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator is not being accepted on VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, babeljs

I added the [@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator) on my ReactJS codebase but for some reason VSCode is complaining about an `expression expected` problem [Screenshot of the current issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKAKM.png). The operator is working, but I wonder if there's any work around for it, besides disabling the vscode main javascript validation (adding `"javascript.validate.enable": false` on the `vscode/settings.json` file)

Comment: Have you found any solution?